# Solving system of ODE with initial value problem (IVP)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential

I have a question about a system of ODE. 
If we have:

$\frac{dx}{dt}=x+2y$

$\frac{dy}{dt}=3x+2y$

with $x(0)=6$ and $y(0)=4$,

how come the solution to the IVP is:

$x(t)=4e^{4t}+2e^{-t}$

$y(t)=6e^{4t}-2e^{-t}$

I tried doing integral by separating the variable but I didn't get that solution. That example & solution are from my numerical method book, please see the attached image

[example & solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PTOMw.png)

Comment: What was your solution?

Comment: $x(t)+2y(t)=14e^{t}$ and $3x(t)+2y(t)=26e^{t}$  I cannot get $e^{4t}$ or $e^{-t}$

Comment: How did you go about getting these numbers?

Comment: For example for $dx/dt$, I separate the variable and use integral, that gives me $ln|x+2y|=t+c_1$. Then I changed the form to $e$, which gives me $x+2y=e^{t+c_1}$. Then it becomes $x+2y=e^{t}e{c_1}$, where $e^{c_1}=C_1$ (a constant).

Comment: That is incorrect, as the derivative of the equation does not match what you started with.

Comment: could you please help? I put the initial value into the equation to get $C_1$ and "C_2" , they are 14 and 26 respectively

Answer (score 5, accepted):

take laplace transform on both sides of both differential equations to get

$(s-1)X(s)=2Y(s)+6  \ \ $ ;

$(s-2)Y(s)=3X(s)+4\\$  respectively

solve for $X(s)$ and $Y(s)$ like algebric equations to give ;

$Y(s)=\dfrac{4s+14}{(s+1)(s-4)}\implies y(t)=-2e^{-t}+6e^{4t}$

$X(s)=\dfrac{6s-4}{(s+1)(s-4)}\implies x(t)=2e^{-t}+4e^{4t}$

Comment: Thank you! looks like i missed some of the steps to solve ODE with IVP

Answer (score 2):

Hint: With $$y=\frac{x'-x}{2}$$ we get
$$y'=3x+\frac{3}{2}(x'-x)$$ and we get $$y'=\frac{x''-x'}{2}$$ so we obtain
$$\frac{x''-x'}{2}=3x+\frac{3}{2}(x'-x)$$
Can you finish?
From here you will get
$$x''-4x'-3x=0$$ make the ansatz $$x=e^{\lambda t}$$

Comment: I'm not too sure how to get the $e$ from there

Comment: Thanks, I'll go check on the $x=e^{\lambda t}$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

One possibility is to eliminate one of the unknowns.

$$x'=x+2y\implies x''=x'+2y'$$ and $$y'=3x+2y=3x+(x'-x),$$

hence

$$x''-3x'-4x=0.$$

Comment: I'm not too sure how to get the e from there

Comment: @JIMBOY: review your theory of univariate linear ODE with constant coefficients.

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider your system of ODE:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x+2y\\\frac{dy}{dt}=3x+2y$$
It follows that
$$\frac{dx}{dt}+\frac{dy}{dt}=4x+4y\rightarrow \frac{d(x+y)}{dt}=4(x+y)\rightarrow \frac{d(x+y)}{x+y}=4dt$$
Integration on both sides yields
$$\ln(x+y)=4t+C\rightarrow x+y=Ce^{4t}\rightarrow y=Ce^{4t}-x$$
Substitution into $\frac{dx}{dt}$ gives
$$\frac{dx}{dt}=x+2(Ce^{4t}-x)\rightarrow \frac{dx}{dt}+x=2Ce^{4t}$$
Multiply by $e^t$ on both sides:
$$\frac{dx}{dt}e^{t}+xe^{t}=2Ce^{5t}\rightarrow\frac{d(xe^{t})}{dt}=2Ce^{5t}$$
Integration on both sides yields
$$xe^{t}=\frac{2C}{5}e^{5t}+K\rightarrow x=\frac{2C}{5}e^{4t}+Ke^{-t}$$
Substitution into $y$ gives
$$y=\frac{3C}{5}e^{4t}-Ke^{-t}$$
Apply conditions:
$$x(0)+y(0)=6+4=10\rightarrow Ce^{4(0)}=10\rightarrow C=10\\x(0)=6\rightarrow \frac{2(10)}{5}e^{4(0)}+Ke^{-(0)}=6\rightarrow K=2$$
Thus,
$$x(t)=4e^{4t}+2e^{-t}\\y(t)=6e^{4t}-2e^{-t}$$

Answer (score 1):

Observe that you have 
$$  \begin{pmatrix} \dot{x} \\ \dot{y} \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 2 \end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \end{pmatrix}  \text{.}  $$
The eigenvalues of this matrix are $4, -1$, so both solutions are of the form $a \mathrm{e}^{4x} + b \mathrm{e}^{-1x}$.  As others have shown, you then match the coefficients to the initial value data.